# Regarding a data structure for O(1) get on prefixes

Tags: java, scala, data-structures, trie, key-value-store

So I am trying to write a little utility in Scala that constantly listens on a bunch of directories for file system changes (deletes, creates, modifications etc) and rsyncs it immediately across to a remote server. (https://github.com/Khalian/LockStep)

My configurations are stored in JSON as the follows:-

```
{
  "localToRemoteDirectories": {
    "/workplace/arunavs/third_party": {
      "remoteDir": "/remoteworkplace/arunavs/third_party",
      "remoteServerAddr": "some Remote server address"
    }
  } 
}
```

This configuration is stored in a Scala Map (key = localDir, value = (remoteDir, remoteServerAddr)). The tuple is represented as a case class

```
sealed case class RemoteLocation(remoteDir:String, remoteServerAddr:String)
```

I am using an actor from a third party:

```
https://github.com/lloydmeta/schwatcher/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/beachape/filemanagement/FileSystemWatchMessageForwardingActor.scala)
```

that listens on these directories (e.g. /workplace/arunavs/third_party and then outputs an Java 7 WatchKind event (EVENT_CREATE, EVENT_MODIFY etc). The problem is that the events sent are absolute path (for instance if I create a file helloworld in third_party dir, the message sent by the actor is (ENTRY_CREATE, /workplace/arunavs/third_party/helloworld))

I need a way to write a getter that gets the nearest prefix from the configuration map stored above. The obvious way to do it is to filter on the map:-

```
def getRootDirsAndRemoteAddrs(localDir:String) : Map[String, RemoteLocation] =
    localToRemoteDirectories.filter(e => localDir.startsWith(e._1))
```

This simply returns the subset of keys that are a prefix to the localDir (in the above example this method is called with localDir = /workplace/arunavs/third_party/helloworld. While this works, this implementation is O(n) where n is the number of items in my configuration. I am looking for better computational complexity (I looked at radix and patricia tries, but they dont cut it since I feeding a string and trying to get keys which are prefixes to it, tries solve the opposite problem).

Comment: Although the question is interesting, my guess is that the cost of this O(N) lookup is completely negligible, especially compared to the time it takes to watch the file system, read files from the disk, and send them to a remote system over the network.

Comment: Yea, its a few orders of a magnitude lesser time taken for in memory ops versus IO, the engineer in me wanted to see if there is a better way.

Comment: I would use a tree, where the children of the node "workplace" are stored in a HashMap<String,Node>. When you get a path like /workplace/foo/bar, then find the node "workplace" in the root map (O(1)), then find foo in the children map of workplace (O(1)), until you don't find a child anymore.

Comment: In Java, you'd use a TreeMap (implements NavigableMap interface).  This interface has several methods to find the key nearest to a given key (either previous or next).  It's O(log N) I believe.